How can I change settings (database, central admin) of a cloned SharePoint 2013 server?
We have a SharePoint 2013 server and Database server hosted on-premise as follows:

SharePoint server: sp1000 (url example: http://sp1000.abc.com)
Database server: db1000 (refered by IP in SharePoint Central Admin)

The customers want to move both SharePoint and DB Server to another physical server. They cloned sp1000 and db1000 to the destination hardware and created:

Cloned SharePoint server: sp2000 (url example: http://sp2000.abc.com)
Cloned Database server: db2000

sp1000 and db1000 are kept running for the time being. Because sp2000 and db2000 are cloned as-is so the following problems occured:

Opening http://sp2000.abc.com shows http://sp1000.abc.com's content
Opening Central Admin in sp2000 (both by sp2000, localhost or IP) shows sp1000's Central Admin.

How can I configure sp2000 (sites and Central Admin) so that it uses the cloned DB server (db2000)? Ultimately I want the cloned server to run as it own, separated from the original SharePoint and DB server.
I'm new to SharePoint and I was tasked with dealing with this problem. Thanks in advance.

Cloning of SharePoint is not supported, You may able to get it work but it will throw a lot unknown errors after it which will be pain.
You can install a refresh SharePoint farm and use content database attaching to use the old content database on the new server.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/administration/attach-or-detach-content-databases?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Thank you very much for your answer.
On the cloned server (sp2000), if I use Product Configuration Wizard to create a new farm, will it create a new (and correct) Central Administration? Currently, on sp2000, Central Admin modifies the setting of original server (sp1000).

yes, it will create  a new CA site.
